# Mass and energy in special relativity [conservation of energy problem]

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy-conservation, mass-energy

A certain quantity of ice at $0$ celsius melts into water at $0$ celsius and in doing so gains $1.00$ kg of mass. What was its initial mass?

Now the problem with my solution is that it of course doesn't meet any expectations of reality, my attempt:

For the ice to melt into liquid water, it needs an amount of heat energy to melt it, which is the latent heat of fusion $L = 334k \frac{J}{Kg}$

then the ice gains an amount $ Q = m_i L$  where $m_i$ is the initial unknown mass of the ice, then $Q = 3.34 x 10^5 m_i$

This amount $Q$ plus the rest energy of the ice $m_i c^2$ is the energy before melting, call it $E_0$

The energy after melting $E$ will be the new rest mass energy $E = m_n c^2$ , where $m_n$ must be the original mass + 1kg, so $m_n = m_i + 1$

then $E = (m_i + 1) c^2$

Energy before = Energy after, then,

$E_0 = E$

$m_i c^2 + 3.34x10^5 m_i = (m_i + 1) c^2$

$3.34x10^5 m_i = c^2$

$m_i = \frac {c^2}{3.34x10^5} = 2.7 x 10^{11} kg$

Which is totally ridiclous, what's wrong here?

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: Hi Khaled and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you got the right answer, this isn't doing your homework for you. Set $\Delta M = 1\,$kg, then:

$$ ML = \Delta M c^2$$

or

$$ M = \frac {\Delta M c^2}L = 2.7\times 10^{11}\,{\rm kg} $$

Now since it asked for the initial mass, maybe you want to include all 12 digits required to distinguish it from the final mass?

$$ M = 269451410204.4\,{\rm kg} $$

but that seems a bit silly, since we don't know $L$ to 12 digits. I used $L=333.55\,$kJ/kg.

Comment: This is weird, nonetheless, thank you, also I'm just trying to understand special relativity better and I'm practicing with these exercises, not necessarily homework.

Comment: I don't think this problem adds a lot of insight into SR, other than $c^2$ is large (one reason we don't notice SR day-to-day). The key to most SR paradoxes is that simultaneity is relative, so that time is *not* a universal parameter ticking away the same for all of some Euclidean space.